# AngularJS ng-click : Adding same Div/Widget on each click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The following code display all the divs one after another :

```
<ul class="record">
   <li id="{{record.id}}" ng-repeat="record in records"> 
      <div> Widget Code.... </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Apart from this I have following clickable list menu at the right side in a drop down fashion :

```
<li ng-repeat="choice in items">
    <a href="#">{{choice}}</a>
</li>
```

Now on click of each list item i want to add the same `<div> Widget Code.... </div>` which append the existing divs on the page.

My recent view is as following now i want to add div on click of each of list item just after the existing divs.

[image]

Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<li ng-repeat="choice in items">
    <a href="#" ng-click="addRecord()">{{choice}}</a>
</li>
```

And then in your controller:

```
var addRecord = function(){
    $scope.records.push({id: 10}); // change to generate your own id
};
```